# Uncaught Exception in worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Here is a snippet which I found in the Python docs:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

[Python Docs: Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

I think above pattern is missing some important features.

For example: If a uncaught exception happens in a worker thread, then this worker does not recover. Sooner or later all workers will break down because an uncaught exception happened.

I guess it is not wise to use above snippet.

In my context I need a simple daemon which runs under systemd (linux).

No message/queue servers like RabbitMQ should be used.

How to get a reliable multithreaded solution?

Unfortunately we need to support Python2.7

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to blindly copy code, and Python documentation examples are primarily intended to demonstrate usage rather than best practice. "In my context I need a simple daemon which runs under systemd (linux)." does not describe your requirements.

Comment: What do you mean by "recover"? If you just want the workers to terminate without causing the whole application to crash (which might be discussed), why don't you just put your worker's code in a `try`?

Comment: @Rightleg yes, I could use try...except but somehow I think this is not all which is needed to get a reliable solution. I don't like re-inventing stuff. Maybe there is already a reliable and proven library?

Comment: After some searching I guess the multiprocessing is better than handling Threads oneself. And multiprocessing was superseded by https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html There is a backport for Python2.7